# Parse number with positive/negative prefix from string in java

Tags: java, formatting

It's quite straight forward in java to parse number from String, i.e. with Integer.parseInt(s) if string in the format *'n'* or *'-n'*, but unfortunately it fails to parse string in the format of *'+n'*.

So what is the most effective/elegant way to parse number from string in java if it contains positive or negative prefix: *'+n'* or *'-n'* ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Integer.parseInt(s.replace("+", ""));
```

In truth there are many gotchas using Integer to parse numbers like that, in that Integer has very specific bounds of size and format ("1,000,000.00") isn't parsing that way, but I'm taking your question as Integer.parseInt meets your needs just fine, you just have to deal with a + in your data.

Comment: java.text.NumberFormat is probably the parser to use, but still doesn't solve the issue with "+".  String.replace(), as demonstrated, does.

Comment: Yes, indeed, I hoped there is some solution based on built-in parsers/formatters...

Comment: @Gennady Shumakher, can you elaborate on the range of possibilities of what you need to parse?

Comment: @Yashai, I am OK with the solution, it's good enough for my use case. In generall, I just feel jdk could provide more elegant way to do that.

Comment: @Gennady, NumberFormat, as Matthew said, is the way to go for serious number parsing. The DecimalFormat subclass is probably the class you want.

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI, this has been fixed in Java 7.

from, [Java SE8 for the Really Impatient](http://books.google.com.pk/books/about/Java_SE_8_for_the_Really_Impatient.html?id=d2CMAgAAQBAJ&redir_esc=y)

> Prior to `JDK 1.7`, what was the result of the following code segment?
>
> `double x = Double.parseDouble("+1.0");`
>
> `int n = Integer.parseInt("+1");`
>
> Pat yourself on the back if you knew the
>   answer: `+1.0` has always been a valid floating-point number, but
>   until Java 7, `+1` was not a valid integer. This has now been fixed
>   for all the various methods that construct `int`, `long`, `short`, `byte`,
>   and `BigInteger` values from strings. There are more of them than you
>   may think. In addition to parse (Int|Long|Short|Byte), there are
>   decode methods that work with hexadecimal and octal inputs, and
>   `valueOf` methods that yield wrapper objects. The `BigInteger(String)`
>   constructor is also updated.