# How to parse String containing '+' symbol

Tags: java

I have a string which has numbers.

I have a code like this,

```
    String tempStr = "+123";
    NumberFormat numformat = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
    numformat.setParseIntegerOnly(true);
    try {
        int ageInDays = Integer.parseInt(tempStr);
        System.out.println("the age in days "+ageInDays);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

It is working fine for the number with negative symbols.But I can't do it for number with '+' symbol. It throws NumberFormatException.

So how can I parse a number with '+' symbol from a string?

Comment: Apparently, since Java 7, you can do `Integer.parseInt("+123");`.  Your code also seems to work for me, but I'm using Java 8.  You might want to have a look at [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2089751/parse-number-with-positive-negative-prefix-from-string-in-java) for more details

Comment: replace the "+" sign with a space or trim it. Technically -123 is a number but +123 is not a number. 123 is the positive number.

Answer (score 4):

In the case you are using Java 7 or higher I would recommend using java.lang.Long; or java.lang.Integer; (if you are sure that you will have to parse integers).

It works for both cases.

Later edit:
I didn't see that you were using Integer.parseInt();

Therefore I assume that you have Java 6 or less.

In this case try calling the following method before the line with `Integer.parseInt(tempStr);` to remove the **+** in case it exists:

```
private static String removePlusSignIfExists(String numberAsString) {
    if(numberAsString == null || numberAsString.length() == 0){
        return numberAsString;
    }

    if(numberAsString.charAt(0) == '+'){
        return numberAsString.substring(1, numberAsString.length());
    } else {
        return numberAsString;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it in Java 6?  Not all of us get to use the latest and greatest...

Comment: I have to admit that I tried it in Java 7 and 8. I do not have the Java 6 SDK for more than one year

Comment: According to the docs, `Long.parseLong` will only work starting with version 7.  So it really doesn't help in this case, since `Integer.parseInt`will work just as well starting with v.7

Comment: Consider adding a "condition" in your answer to highlight that this is a change which has been added to Java 7+ for future readers ;)

Comment: Thank you for suggestions, I will re-edit my post according to

Comment: @MadProgrammer Java 7 is hardly the "latest and greatest" at this point `:P`

Comment: @MattBall  I added a solution for Java6 or less in any case. In my context I didn't used it since I didn't had projects that strictly required it.

Comment: @MattBall We're stilling using Java 6 and will likely to do so into the foreseeable future.  I don't disagree, but that fact that the OP is having the issue at all suggests that they aren't using Java 7+ :P

Answer (score 2):

This function basically replaces **"+"** with **""**, a blank string, so **"+12+3"** will return **123**.

```
public int parseInt(String text) {
    return Integer.parseInt(text.replaceAll("+", ""));
}
```

An example of how to use this is

```
System.out.println(parseInt("+123")); //Returns 123
```

I hope this helped!